# I'm making a basic Quiz on Javascript, but I'm not getting any results at all. What are the errors in my code & what do i need to do?

Tags: javascript, html

There are 3 criterions i need to fulfill:

- The script should display the number of correct answers and the
  percentage correct at the bottom of the quiz.
- Display the text ‘Well Done’ if all questions were
  answered correctly or ‘Try again’ if not.
- A hyperlink on 'Try Again' to reload the page.

I haven't yet gotten to the second & third criteria's because I'm not able display score for a trial of the first question.
I've tried to use two different methods but since I haven't completely understood `switch`, I don't think I'm using it right.
I have also tried to inspect element, but it does not show any errors.
I'm still a student & an amateur in JavaScript (& coding in general) so I would appreciate solutions which are simple & not overly complicated.

Thanks!

```html
<title>JS Quiz template</title>

</head>

<body>
 <div align="center">
    <h3>Quiz Trial</h3>
 </div>
 
What does RAM stand for?<br>
1. Random Arithmetic Maths<br>
2. Random Access Memory<br>
3. Regional Accounting Money<br>
Answer 1:
<input id="RAM" type="number" size="4"><br><br>
What does ADC stand for?<br>
1. Asynchronous DialUp Call<br>
2. Active Database Chip<br>
3. Analog to Digital Converter<br>
Answer 2:
<input id="ADC" type="number" size="4" ><br><br>
What does AGP stand for?<br>
1. Active Graphics Pointer<br>
2. Accelerated Graphics Port<br>
3. Analog Gateway Protocol<br>
Answer 3: 
<input id="AGP" type="number" size="4"><br><br>
What does Laser stand for?<br>
1. Light and sound emitting range <br>
2. Light Amplification by Stimulated Emission of Radiation.<br>
3. Lightening around lithosphere enchanted road <br>
Answer 4:
<input id="LAS" type="number" size="4"><br><br>
What does CPU stand for?<br>
1. Central Processing Unit<br>
2. Control Primary Unit<br>
3. Central Personal Unit<br>
Answer 5: 
<input id="CPU" type="number" size="4" ><br><br>
<button type="button" onClick="QuizFunction()">Test your answers</button>
<br>
<p id="pstyle">Number of correct answers</p>
 
<script>

function QuizFunction() {
    var ans1 = document.getElementById('RAM').value;
        ans2 = document.getElementById('ADC').value;
        ans3 = document.getElementById('AGP').value;
        ans4 = document.getElementById('LAS').value;
        ans5 = document.getElementById('CPU').value;
        score = 0

            function QuizFunction() {
                if(ans1= 2){var score=score++;
                            document.getElementById('pstyle').innerHTML(score+'/5');}
                else{document.getElementById('pstyle').innerHTML(score+'/5')}
            }
}

/**
function QuizFunction() 
        {
    var ans1 = document.getElementById('RAM').value;
        ans2 = document.getElementById('ADC').value;
        ans3 = document.getElementById('AGP').value;
        ans4 = document.getElementById('LAS').value;
        ans5 = document.getElementById('CPU').value;
        score = 0


            switch(ans1){
                case "2":
                     score=score+1
                default:
                     score=score
            }
            switch(ans2){
                case "3":
                     score=score+1
                default:
                     score=score
            }
            switch(ans3){
                case "3":
                     score=score+1
                default:
                     score=score
            }
            switch(ans4){
                case "2":
                     score=score+1
                default:
                     score=score
            }
            switch(ans5){
                case "1":
                     score=score+1
                default:
                     score=score
            }

    document.getElementById('pstyle').innerHTML(score+"/5"+"</br>"+(score/5)*100+"%")
        }
**/

</script>

</body>
```

Comment: Have you opened your developer tools and look at the Console to see any error messages? That's where you should start as it will tell you what line(s) the errors are on and a message that tells a little about the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `QuizFunction`, which produces the results, nested inside of `QuizFunction`. Take the code from the nested function and put it in the first one. Then delete the nested function.

Then your code will run, but you'll get an error with `.innerHTML` because you are putting parenthesis after it and attempting to pass it an argument as if it was a function, but it's a property, so you need to put `=` after it and assign it your value.

Beyond that, you really shouldn't use `input type=number` unless you restrict the input to the number of answers to choose from, which you can do by adding the `min` and `max` attributes. In reality, using `input type="radio"` for each possible answer is the best UI to use.

```html
<title>JS Quiz template</title>

</head>

<body>
 <div align="center">
    <h3>Quiz Trial</h3>
 </div>
 
What does RAM stand for?<br>
1. Random Arithmetic Maths<br>
2. Random Access Memory<br>
3. Regional Accounting Money<br>
Answer 1:
<input id="RAM" type="number" size="4" min="1" max="3"><br><br>
What does ADC stand for?<br>
1. Asynchronous DialUp Call<br>
2. Active Database Chip<br>
3. Analog to Digital Converter<br>
Answer 2:
<input id="ADC" type="number" size="4" min="1" max="3"><br><br>
What does AGP stand for?<br>
1. Active Graphics Pointer<br>
2. Accelerated Graphics Port<br>
3. Analog Gateway Protocol<br>
Answer 3: 
<input id="AGP" type="number" size="4" min="1" max="3"><br><br>
What does Laser stand for?<br>
1. Light and sound emitting range <br>
2. Light Amplification by Stimulated Emission of Radiation.<br>
3. Lightening around lithosphere enchanted road <br>
Answer 4:
<input id="LAS" type="number" size="4" min="1" max="3"><br><br>
What does CPU stand for?<br>
1. Central Processing Unit<br>
2. Control Primary Unit<br>
3. Central Personal Unit<br>
Answer 5: 
<input id="CPU" type="number" size="4" ><br><br>
<button type="button" onClick="QuizFunction()">Test your answers</button>
<br>
<p id="pstyle">Number of correct answers</p>
 
<script>

function QuizFunction() {
    var ans1 = document.getElementById('RAM').value;
        ans2 = document.getElementById('ADC').value;
        ans3 = document.getElementById('AGP').value;
        ans4 = document.getElementById('LAS').value;
        ans5 = document.getElementById('CPU').value;
        score = 0
                if(ans1= 2){var score=score++;
                  document.getElementById('pstyle').innerHTML = score+'/5';
                } else {
                  document.getElementById('pstyle').innerHTML  score+'/5';
                }
}

</script>

</body>
```

Comment: Oh right, i did not notice that. Ive corrected it, however now the next problem is that the score does not display below the "Numbe of correct answers". I know the code works because i replaced the `document.getElementById('pstyle).innerHTML` with `alert`. How do I make it display the score & the percentage below?

Comment: If i replace that with `document.write`, the whole page disappears & only the score is displayed.

Comment: @Dhruv That's a different question than what you have asked here. You should post a new question that focuses on just that problem and mark this answer as "the" answer to the question you have asked here.

Comment: Don't use `document.write()`. You need to spend some time learning about the [Document Object Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model). We're not a tutorial site here. We expect that you'll do your research and learning first and then only post when you have issues with that.

Answer (score -1):

The problem with your code was you have nested the function named as **QuizFunction** and after that you have in the **.innerHTML** you have made a mistake of using **()** this parenthesis which is not used instead **"="**  is used...I have fixed the code and commented the edit part you can take a look at that...

Here is the fixed code....

Hope this will be the one you are trying to do....

```js
function QuizFunction() {
    var ans1 = document.getElementById('RAM').value;
    var ans2 = document.getElementById('ADC').value;
    var ans3 = document.getElementById('AGP').value;
    var ans4 = document.getElementById('LAS').value;
    var ans5 = document.getElementById('CPU').value;
    var score = 0

                if(ans1 == 2){
                score=score+1;// removed var from this because you have initialized it already
                }else if(ans2 == 3){
                score=score+1;          
                }else if(ans3 == 2){
                score=score+1;
                }else if(ans4 == 2){
                score=score+1;
                }else if(ans5 == 1){
                score=score+1;
                }
                 document.getElementById('pstyle').innerHTML = score+'/5'; //removed paranthesis and used "=" equal to for assigning
                
                
}

/**
function QuizFunction()
        {
    var ans1 = document.getElementById('RAM').value;
        ans2 = document.getElementById('ADC').value;
        ans3 = document.getElementById('AGP').value;
        ans4 = document.getElementById('LAS').value;
        ans5 = document.getElementById('CPU').value;
        score = 0


            switch(ans1){
                case "2":
                     score=score+1
                default:
                     score=score
            }
            switch(ans2){
                case "3":
                     score=score+1
                default:
                     score=score
            }
            switch(ans3){
                case "3":
                     score=score+1
                default:
                     score=score
            }
            switch(ans4){
                case "2":
                     score=score+1
                default:
                     score=score
            }
            switch(ans5){
                case "1":
                     score=score+1
                default:
                     score=score
            }

    document.getElementById('pstyle').innerHTML(score+"/5"+"</br>"+(score/5)*100+"%")
        }
**/
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>JS Quiz template</title>

</head>

<body>
 <div align="center">
    <h3>Quiz Trial</h3>
 </div>
 
What does RAM stand for?<br>
1. Random Arithmetic Maths<br>
2. Random Access Memory<br>
3. Regional Accounting Money<br>
Answer 1:
<input id="RAM" type="number" size="4"><br><br>
What does ADC stand for?<br>
1. Asynchronous DialUp Call<br>
2. Active Database Chip<br>
3. Analog to Digital Converter<br>
Answer 2:
<input id="ADC" type="number" size="4" ><br><br>
What does AGP stand for?<br>
1. Active Graphics Pointer<br>
2. Accelerated Graphics Port<br>
3. Analog Gateway Protocol<br>
Answer 3: 
<input id="AGP" type="number" size="4"><br><br>
What does Laser stand for?<br>
1. Light and sound emitting range <br>
2. Light Amplification by Stimulated Emission of Radiation.<br>
3. Lightening around lithosphere enchanted road <br>
Answer 4:
<input id="LAS" type="number" size="4"><br><br>
What does CPU stand for?<br>
1. Central Processing Unit<br>
2. Control Primary Unit<br>
3. Central Personal Unit<br>
Answer 5: 
<input id="CPU" type="number" size="4" ><br><br>
<button type="button" onClick="QuizFunction()">Test your answers</button>
<br>
<p id="pstyle">Number of correct answers</p>
 




</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Just posting working code is not a good answer here. Please take the time to read about [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).